# Django I'm trying do perform a simple task, display on the page whatever was input in a textfield

Tags: python, html, django

All I want is the user to type in something in a single textfield and have the input displayed on the same page by the form. Please help!!!!

I tried so many solutions nothing seems to work and its such a simple task

please see my code:

views.py

```
def math_drills(request):

    num1 = random.randint(0,100)
    num2 = random.randint(0,100)
    total = num2 + num1
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Addition(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            u_i = request.POST['uans']
            return redirect('math_drills_url')
    return render(request,'math_drills.html',{
        'num1':num1,
        'num2':num2,

        'total':total,
    })

html
```

```
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    
                </script>

                <label class="" id="num1" name="">{{num1}}</label> + 
                <label class="" id="num2" name="">{{num2}}</label> =

                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="uans" value="" id="" style="width:2%;">
                    <input type="submit" value="add">
                </form>

            </div>
```

Comment: What problem exactly you're facing ? You're not rendering your form in **GET** method.

Comment: I'm trying to have a user type a number in the textfield click on a button and simply have the inout displayed on the same page next to the form. That's all

Comment: So are you storing user input in database? if not you can do this by javascript if you want to send your input to server use [Ajax](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)